# SoftLayer: Do softlayer resource ids change from order to order?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Do softlayer resource ids change from order to order? I learned that hardware ids and subnet ids wouldn't change from order to order, so if you cancel a hardware (id=123), next time when you order a new hardware in the same data center, it's possible that the hardware with id 123 may be assigned to you again.

But VSI ids are quite different, they are changed from order to order. So you always get a new VSI id.

How about storage (SoftLayer_Network_Storage) and vlan (SoftLayer_Network_Vlan)?

Answer (score 0):

Currently information about ID allocation is an implementation detail and the users should not assume one behavior or another.